# Make length persistent between subfigures

Tags: floats, environments, subcaption, lengths

I am trying to have two subfigures have the same height and have defined a length for this purpose, but the length gets set to zero between them. My understanding is that this is tied to the subfigure environment. Is there any way to make this work?

small version of picture, for reference

[image: smiley]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \newlength\mycustomlen
    \setlength\mycustomlen{50pt}
    \includegraphics[height=\mycustomlen]{smiley.png}
    \caption{height is mycustomlen: \the\mycustomlen}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=\mycustomlen]{smiley.png}
    \caption{this picture doesnt show up\\
    mycustomlen: \the\mycustomlen}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Set it before the subfigure not inside it (inside an env most changes to variables are local). Also, put the `\newlength` in the preamble.

Comment: thanks for both the answer and the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the length outside of the subfigure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newlength\mycustomlen

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setlength\mycustomlen{50pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=\mycustomlen]{smiley.png}
    \caption{height is mycustomlen: \the\mycustomlen}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[height=\mycustomlen]{smiley.png}
    \caption{this picture doesnt show up\\
    mycustomlen: \the\mycustomlen}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if I c0orrectly understood your problem, than for equal height images you not need to define special length, but just use `\setkeys{Gin}{height=<desired height of images>}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\setkeys{Gin}{height=50pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}  %{smiley.png}
\caption{height is mycustomlen: \the\mycustomlen}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}  %{smiley.png}
\caption{this picture doesn't show up\\
         mycustomlen: \the\mycustomlen}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(since i haven't smile picture, I use the standard example picture ).